# Slight scrape/cut along sidewall of tire after hitting curb

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

Was not paying enough attention and scraped against a curb yesterday. I scraped up a little of the hubcap but also noticed a slight cut in the rubber on the sidewall of the tire. I can hardly fit my nail into it. It's not deep at all. Shops are closed today, just wondering if I can get an opinion about the severity of this cut. I know, in general, sidewall damage can be bad. Thanks for your help![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sidewall is absolutely fine. There are many questions here about much deeper sidewall cuts, and usually the advice is to replace the tire, but for such a minor scrape, you have absolutely no danger.

The scrape is just barely touching the surface of the sidewall. There is some amount of rubber protection in the sidewall, so no way can it affect the true structural part of the tire, the cords.

Just continue driving on the tire and be happy that your damage was not deeper!

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what my fiancee said as well and was what I kind of thought too. I'm just being extra paranoid after googling. Thanking whatever that I didn't cause more damage. Phew!